# Adding value of cookie with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I have a system that sets a cookie named of "chk" to value "0". Now I need, using htaccess, to add this value +1 everytime the user hits my server. I am trying the code below but it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)?chk=([0-9]+)(;|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NE,R=302,CO=chk:%2 + 1:localhost:1:/:false:false]
```

On the third line I try to add "+1" to the value captured on the second line but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment to the answer provided by some guy here (the answer was removed for some reason):

Your code almost worked! The problem is that the cookie "chk" is concatenating the value instead of suming "+1". I need 1 to become 2, 2 to become 3... your code makes 1 become "1+1", 2 to become "2+1"... any idea how to fix this? With this fix you answered works perfecetly!

Comment: What language are you using? I personally would do this in PHP. It's much easier and don't have to mess with .htaccess for this.

Comment: @Starkeen didnt work cause %1 is matching -> (^|;)

Comment: @PanamaJack you are right, PHP is muuuch easier but this server for security reasons cant interpret languages like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to redirect the request ,let the request pass through untouched 
:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)?chk=([0-9+]+)(;|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [CO=chk:%2+1:localhost:1:/]
```

Comment: %2+1 is concatenating, I need it to sum. Any idea?

Comment: Your suggestion of letting the request pass is really nice but the cookie is not summing it's concatenating. Can you check this?

Comment: Apache doesnt calculate numbers in cookie value, it treats numbers as string, that is why 1+1 becomes 1+1 not 2